# How to get the distance from center when using geoflutterfire with flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I am using the [geoflutterfire2](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2) package to retrieve data within a certain radius. The documentation mention that for each document you can even get the distance from center.

This is a code snippet that I got from [Jeff Delaney](https://github.com/fireship-io/167-flutter-geolocation-firestore/blob/master/lib/main.dart) tutorial on GeoFlutter.

```
documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    GeoPoint pos = document.data['position']['geopoint'];
    double distance = document.data['distance'];
```

But I as have learned, I could get the same result just by doing

```
documentList.forEach((DocumentSnapshot document) {
    GeoPoint pos = document['position']['geopoint'];
    double distance = document['distance'];
```

So far so gut. Unfortunately I get `error with distance: Bad state: field "distance" does not exist`.

Am using geoflutterfire2 wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [GeoFlutterFire2 docs](https://pub.dev/packages/geoflutterfire2):

> Geo Calculations
> `point.distance(latitude, longitude)` Haversine distance to a point

This value is **not stored** in the database, but rather a [`distance()` method on the `GeoFirePoint` class](https://pub.dev/documentation/geoflutterfire2/latest/geoflutterfire2/GeoFirePoint/distance.html). So you'll have to get or create a point based on the lat/lon and then call `distance` on that.

Since you currently have a [`GeoPoint` object](https://pub.dev/documentation/cloud_firestore/latest/cloud_firestore/GeoPoint-class.html), it'd be something like:

```
GeoPoint pos = document['position']['geopoint'];
GeoFirePoint pos2 = geo.point(latitude: pos.latitude, longitude: pos.longitude);
double distance = pos2.distance(37.3861, 122.0839);
```